# TinyButStrong (and OpenTbs) library not working

Tags: 8, composer

Download the lib from the web, script outside of Drupal with two include_once() and it works perfectly well. But reading questions and answers here show me this is no longer an option in a Drupal 8 controller. Fine.

```
composer require tinybutstrong/tinybutstrong
composer require tinybutstrong/opentbs
```

Those 2 commands put the code in my vendor dir and eventually the autoloader (replacing include_once) is doing its job fine : cloning all the code in my controller and I got a fatal error saying "Cannot declare class TinyButStrong\clsTbsLocator, because the name is already in use in (...)htdocs/vendor/tinybutstrong/tinybutstrong/tbs_class.php.

I suppose now I'm missing a use statement in my controller. Tried (a lot of!) options with no luck, for example :

```
namespace TinyButStrong; # at the beginnig of vendor/.../tbs_class.php and
use TinyButStrong\clsTinyButStrong; # before my method in my controller...
```

Also, I've read "one class per file". But tbs_class.php contains several define and 3 classes. Will I be force to cut it in several files (and forget install with composer) ?

Thanks in advance.
Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including a library with composer doesn't change how it works and its class/namespace structure.

It doesn't get namespaces automatically, there is no correlation between package names and namespaces.

Looking at https://github.com/Skrol29/tinybutstrong, it doesn't seem to use namespaces and has everything in a single file.

So that's exactly how you still have to use it, just refer to the global namespace with `new \clsTinyButStrong()`.

If that doesn't work then the you need to report that there as a bug, it is responsible for telling composer where to load its files.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved my day.Tried with parentheses but never with backslash